# How to pass HTML and special characters with an object in Vue props

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a component which should display a dictionary of words that I pass through the props.

I pass an array of words and their descriptions. The problem is that I also want to have links in the descriptions. Following the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-an-Object) I came up with this:

```html
<Dictionary v-bind:entries="[{word: 'A', description: 'A letter A'}, {word: 'B', description: 'A letter B'}]"
```

In the component itself, I iterate through this array and display a nice dictionary with words grouped by words.

The problem arises when I want to do somthing like this:

```html
<Dictionary v-bind:entries="[{word: 'A', description: 'A letter A. Read more <a href="www.lettera.com">here</a>'}, {word: 'B', description: 'A letter B. It's awesome'}]"
```

There are 2 problems:

- passing HTML as part of description
- using `'` character in B's description is registered as an end of the description string.

How can I solve this?

Comment: add single quotes for the href value as well jus like follows...............


 "[{word: 'A', description: 'A letter A. Read more <a href='www.lettera.com'>here</a>'}, {word: 'B', description: 'A letter B. It's awesome'}]"

Answer (score 4):

> passing HTML as part of description

You can inject HTML through [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) in Vue components, simply pass in a HTML string.

> using ' character in B's description is registered as an end of the description string.

You can escape the `'` character in the HTML string value using `\`

Please check this [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-turing-ppsuv?file=/src/App.vue) for a working demo.